# How to show data in treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

[image: Please follow the image]

I want to show the data in above format. The number of children are dynamic. How can I do it by using recursive function or having any simple way.

Comment: and this is ? WinForms, Web, WPF ? Also provide some sample code where you are stuck with.

Comment: It is a winForms and TreeView control. I want to do it by recursive functionality.

Comment: Can you show us your DataObjects or what else you want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the solution. In fact, It is

```
private TreeNode GenerateDataModel(TreeNode TrvNode, int PositionIndex) {
        foreach (var grpData in ApplicationManager.GetGroupingInfo().Where(x => x.PositionIndex == PositionIndex)) {
            string sectionQuery = Query + " Select Distinct(" + grpData.Fieldname + ") from DataTbl" +
                (TrvNode == null ? string.Empty : " where " + TrvNode.Tag.ToString()) +
                " order by " + grpData.Fieldname + " " + (grpData.OrderBy == GroupOrder.Descending ? "Desc" : string.Empty);
            appMgr.ExecuteQuery(sectionQuery);
            DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
            appMgr.GetData(ref dSet);

            foreach (DataRow dtRow in dSet.Tables[0].Rows) {
                string con = string.Empty;
                if (TrvNode != null)
                    con = TrvNode.Tag.ToString() + " And ";

                TreeNode trvNode = new TreeNode() {
                    Text = dtRow[grpData.Fieldname].ToString(),
                    Tag = con + grpData.Fieldname + "='" + dtRow[grpData.Fieldname].ToString() + "'"
                };

                TreeNode retTreeNode = GenerateDataModel(trvNode, PositionIndex + 1);
                if (TrvNode == null)
                    trvGroupDataModel.Nodes.Add(trvNode);
                else {
                    TrvNode.Nodes.Add(trvNode);
                }
            }
        }

        return TrvNode;
    }
```

Here PositionIndex is nothing but the Sorting order index.
For ex.

```
Select * from <Table> Order by P1 Desc, P2, P2
```

P1, P2 and P3 are represented in 0,1 and 2 index form.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't specified format of your data I just illustrate the idea. Pseudocode:

```
class YourType
{
   public List<YourType> Childs;
   public string Name;
}

void recursiveMethod(List<YourType> parents)
{
  foreach(YourType parent in parents)
  {
    Node parentNode = new Node(parent.Name);
    treeView.Nodes.Add(parentNode);
    if(parent.Childs.Count > 0) //we have child nodes
      recursiveMethod(parent.Childs); //recursion
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do that. You could specify the source, which could be a depedency property or an observable collection, and bind to it or you could do it without binding. It will help if you could make your question more descriptive.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49ce00c7-4d6d-4900-9fa3-a3913302b7bc/treeview-binding-with-generic-list

Comment: This is for WPF. He is using WinForms